# What is the math to translate a plane by rotating a circle simulating a real world wheel rolling on the ground?

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, geometry, angle

This is like a big secret on the internet.

In all the games I can find the wheel rotates slower or faster then it should relative to the ground movement.

Given `radius of the circle` and the `intersection point with the plane at 90 deg` angle `translate the ground on X axis` to simulate the real world rolling of a wheel on the ground.

In the example bellow mouse over the circle to rotate it. The ground bellow should move as you would expect in the real world.

```js
const plane = $('#plane')
const planeX = plane.offset().left
const wheel = $('#wheel>div')
const radius = wheel.width() / 2
let degrees = 0
const offset = wheel.parent().offset()
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.interactive', event => {
  $('.interactive').css('background', 'rgba(172, 255, 47, 0.25)')
  const radians = Math.atan2(
    event.pageX - (offset.left + radius),
    event.pageY - (offset.top + radius)
  )
  const degreeWheelOffset = radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1 - degrees // to start from where left off
  $(document).on('mousemove', event2 => {
    const radians = Math.atan2(
      event2.pageX - (offset.left + radius),
      event2.pageY - (offset.top + radius)
    )
    degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1 - degreeWheelOffset
    wheel.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)').data('degree', degrees)
    plane.css('left', planeX - (Math.sin(radians) * radius) + 'px')
  })
})
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.interactive', () => {
  $('.interactive').css('background', '')
  $(document).off('mousemove')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wheel" style="position:fixed;bottom:1em;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);">
    <div style="width:150px;height:150px;border:1px solid;border-radius:50%;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')">
      <div class="interactive" style="border-radius:50%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0"></div>
      <div style="position: absolute;top:50%;bottom:0;left:50%;border-left:1px solid;"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div id="plane" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:-100vw;width:300vw;height:1em;border:1px solid;display:flex;justify-content:space-around;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')"><b>1</b><b>2</b><b>3</b><b>4</b><b>5</b><b>6</b><b>7</b><b>8</b><b>9</b></div>
```

Comment: @meowgoesthedog don't give it away!  If this secret gets out we're finished!

Comment: @Pointy I have sinned against my brethren and shall burn for eternity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple answer

For each invocation of `mousemove`:

- Compute the change in mouse coordinate from the previous invocation
- Calculate the **signed** change in angle that this mouse movement produces
- Add this to a global accumulated angle
- Calculate the horizontal translation = (global angle in radians) * (radius of wheel)

The signed change in angle is given by the *cross-product* between the vectors in the below diagram:

[image]

[image]

It is better to use `atan2` though, for numerical stability near the 90-degree points:

[image]

(I'm certain that at least one of the established geometry gurus here - e.g. Yves Daoust - has a post explaining how the above works, so I won't do so here.)

Working code:

```js
const plane = $('#plane')
const planeX = plane.offset().left
const wheel = $('#wheel>div')
const radius = wheel.width() / 2
const offset = wheel.parent().offset()

let degrees = 0;
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.interactive', event => {
  $('.interactive').css('background', 'rgba(172, 255, 47, 0.25)')
  let mouseX1 = event.pageX, mouseY1 = event.pageY;
  $(document).on('mousemove', event2 => {
    const mouseX2 = event2.pageX, mouseY2 = event2.pageY;

    // center position
    const centerX = offset.left + radius, 
          centerY = offset.top + radius;

    // vectors A - C and B - C
    const deltaX1 = mouseX1 - centerX, deltaY1 = mouseY1 - centerY;
    const deltaX2 = mouseX2 - centerX, deltaY2 = mouseY2 - centerY;

    // change in angle formula
    const deltaA = Math.atan2(deltaX1 * deltaY2 - deltaY1 * deltaX2,
                              deltaX1 * deltaX2 + deltaY1 * deltaY2);
  
    // increment
    degrees += deltaA * (180 / Math.PI);
    const radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

    // set previous coordinates
    mouseX1 = mouseX2; mouseY1 = mouseY2;

    // apply
    wheel.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)').data('degree', degrees)
    plane.css('left', planeX - radians * radius + 'px') // simpler formula
  })
})
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.interactive', () => {
  $('.interactive').css('background', '')
  $(document).off('mousemove')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wheel" style="position:fixed;bottom:1em;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);">
    <div style="width:150px;height:150px;border:1px solid;border-radius:50%;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')">
      <div class="interactive" style="border-radius:50%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0"></div>
      <div style="position: absolute;top:50%;bottom:0;left:50%;border-left:1px solid;"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div id="plane" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:-100vw;width:300vw;height:1em;border:1px solid;display:flex;justify-content:space-around;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')"><b>1</b><b>2</b><b>3</b><b>4</b><b>5</b><b>6</b><b>7</b><b>8</b><b>9</b></div>
```

---

**Slightly more complex answer**

The above code makes the approximation that during a mouse polling cycle (the interval between consecutive `mousemove` calls) the wheel remains stationary. For continuous movement this is of course not true - the center of the wheel is constantly moving along with the mouse.

From this arises a *first-order non-linear differential equation* which gives the "physically correct" delta angle per mouse movement (I won't show the derivation here):

[image]

Where `m` is the mouse position, `p` is the wheel position, and `theta` is the accumulated angle. With some variable substitution and re-arranging this can be solved analytically; otherwise it can be easily integrated numerically with e.g. adaptive RK4.

... But of course, if the polling frequency is sufficiently high (which it usually is) – i.e. the delta angle per poll cycle is small, then the approximation is more than accurate enough.

Comment: This answer is awesome and will work perfect for the situation with mouse/touch events. I will also randomly rotate the wheel and I am thinking at a function like `const engine=(rotate=5,radius=150)=>return number // distance to translate the plane` then I can translate the plane with `setInterval=(()=> plane.css('left', engine(second===1 ? 5 : second===2 ? 10 : 0) + 'px') ,10)` . The `engine` function will also work when rotating the wheel with the mouse `plane.css('left', prevPlaneX-engine(prevDegree-degree) + 'px') `. An append to your answer on how will you approach this will be awesome.

Comment: @Alqin I think that's too broad for a single SO question (also a little unclear what you are asking). However if you have a power source for the wheel then it might be best to use a "physics engine" approach, i.e. use forces / impulses instead of direct rotation changes. I suggest making a new post with more details and examples of what you want to achieve. In the meantime though I'll have a think about this.

Comment: I am trying to create a 3D world in Three.js. I want to move the camera around by rotating wheels on the screen because why not. In my mind I rotate the wheel and that rotation `engine(degree,radius)` will return how much I should translate the plane. Then I want to create an autopilot that takes you to places with `requestAnimationFrame`  and `engine(degree,radius)` degree here will have different value on different times. I really want everything to depend on the spinning of the wheel like in the real world.I don't want to use a physics engine for this.

Comment: @Alqin I put "physics engine" in quotes because you don't have to use a fully-fledged engine, just some basic force / motion equations in place of direct angle changes. Also it seems very far-fetched to make the leap from 2D to 3D based on a few SO answers, and I don't see the connection between your 3D problem with this one.

Answer (score 1):

When the vehicle advances 2π m, the wheel rolls 2π m, i.e. an angle of 2π/r radian.

When the vehicle advances d m, the wheel rolls d m, i.e. an angle of d/r radian.